# Why does my navbar appear on top of scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar, parallax

I'm trying to create my first website with parallax effect. I noticed a problem with my fixed top navbar - it appears on top of the scrollbar and overflow hidden doesn't hide it. I've tried to put it into .main-container and it kinda solves my problem: it's not on the top of scrollbar anymore, however, it stops being top fixed. What causes this problem? How can I fix it?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"></link>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg" id="top-navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" id='nav-icon' type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                            <span></span>
                                            <span></span>
                                            <span></span>
                                            <span></span>
                                        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href='#1'>link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href='#2'>link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href='#3'>link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href='#4'>link 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbar-dropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">dropdown</a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>

                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class='main-container'>

        <div class="parallax-container">

            <div>
                <h1>title</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#1" id='main-anchor'>
                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 5rem" id='goto-icon'>
                    keyboard_arrow_down
                </i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper" class='content-container'>

            <div id="page-content" class="page content">

                <span class="anchor" id="1"></span>

                <section class="card text-white bg-dark mb-5">
                    <h4 class="card-header">Title</h4>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <span class="anchor" id="2"></span>

                <section class="card text-white bg-dark mb-5">
                    <h4 class="card-header">Title</h4>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <span class="anchor" id="3"></span>

                <section class="card text-white bg-dark mb-5">
                    <h4 class="card-header">Title</h4>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <span class="anchor" id="4"></span>

                <section class="card text-white bg-dark mb-5">
                    <h4 class="card-header">Title</h4>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

SCSS

```
// COLORS
$darker: #212529;
$dark: #35383C;
$gray: #605F5E;
$greenish: #0F5158;
$lightgreen: #21686E;
$blue: #7FA5A6;
$lightblue: #96B5B6;
$alabaster: #F1EBE1;
$gainsboro: #CEE0DC;
// SITE
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: $darker;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.main-container {
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: $darker;
    a {
        &:link,
        &:visited,
        &:hover,
        &:active {
            color: white;
        }
    }
}

.content-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: $darker;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 75px 0;
}

.parallax-container {
    color: white;
    left: -9px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 101vw;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

// NAVBAR
#top-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    z-index: 30;
    line-height: 150%;
    background-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
    padding: 0 2.5vw;
    transition: transform 1s .3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 50px -28px $blue;
    &.dark {
        background: $darker;
    }
    &.dark-show {
        background: $darker;
    }
    &.scrollUp {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    * {
        color: #bbccdd !important;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .nav-item {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 0 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        // &:hover:not(.dropdown) {
        //     background-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, 1);
        // }
        a:hover {
            color: white !important;
        }
    }
    .nav-link {
        margin: 10px 0;
        &.active {
            color: white !important;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        border-color: $blue;
        line-height: 2rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        .dropdown-divider {
            margin: 0;
            border-top: 2px solid black;
        }
        .dropdown-item:hover {
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
        }
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        color: $blue;
    }
}

// HAMBURGER
#nav-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background: $blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 1px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 13px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: 0px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 15px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 15px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}

// CONTENT
#page-content {
    height: 100vh !important;
    padding: 15vh 10vw 5vh 10vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 15vh;
    margin-top: -15vh;
    visibility: hidden;
}

// MEDIA QUERIES
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    #page-content {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translateX(200px)')
    $('#nav-icon').click(function() {
        // $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#top-navbar').toggleClass('dark-show');
    });
    $('.main-container').scroll(function() {
        let pageHeight = $('.main-container').height();
        $('#top-navbar').toggleClass('dark', $(this).scrollTop() > pageHeight);
        $('section').each(function(i) {
            var position = $(document).scrollTop();
            var header = $('#top-navbar').outerHeight();
            if ($(this).position().top <= (position + header)) {
                var top = $(this).position().top;
                console.log($(this).position().top <= (position + header));
                $(".nav-link.active").removeClass('active');
                $(".nav-link").eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        })
    });
    $('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});

document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});

let width = $(window).width();
let height = $(window).height();

if (height > width && height < 1024) {
    let position = $('#page-content').scrollTop();

    $('.main-container').scroll(function() {
        let scroll = $('.main-container').scrollTop();
        if (scroll > position) {
            $('#top-navbar').addClass('scrollUp');
        } else {
            $('#top-navbar').removeClass('scrollUp');
        }
        position = scroll;
    });
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/strzesia/fhqok4ym/19/

Comment: i didn't checked it thoroughly but removing your main-container class solves the issue of navbar overflow

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it also removes parallax effect which I want to keep.

Comment: It seems a problem with your `main-container` class. Have you tried using a [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-fixed-top) fixed navbar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css for navbar

```
.nav{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;      
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work - either at all, when I don't modify my existing code, or creates a second scrollbar when I remove position: fixed from #top-navbar

Comment: Can you give more information about question? What I can get from question is that you want your navigation bar to be fixed on top.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was using a Bootstrap template from a teacher. I found out the problem was this line:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I **just removed** and it solved the problem.